# How to have jquery function run on page load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this jQuery function that enables a `Search` button next to a `Search` field when there is input:

```
$('form#search').on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
        $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').removeProp("disabled");
    } else {
        $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    event.preventDefault();     
});
```

It would be nice if this function could run automatically on `page load` as well, not only on `keyup`.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check(){
    var text=$("form#search input[type=text]");
    if (text.val().length != 0) {
            text.next('input[type="submit"]').removeProp("disabled");
    } else {
            text.next('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
}

$(function(){
    //trigger when the text field is being filled with text
    $('form#search').on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
        check();
    });
    //trigger when the document is loaded
    check();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can this function be triggered on keyup as well?

Comment: Trigger by what but keyup event?if nothing,can be create a thread to check,I've edited my answer for this,hope this is helpful to you

Comment: Hmm the function `check()` should be triggered on two events: when the document is being loaded AND when the text field is being filled with text. This interval thing is not ideal for me...

Comment: Understand,actually I think you do not need these,
only add `$(function(){$('form#search').trigger('keyup');});` to trigger when the document is being loaded,
and the original code when the text field is being filled with text

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('form#search').trigger('keyup');
});
```

Comment: `triggerHandler` might be even nicer as it won't have any (possible) side effects